# Swashbuckle and Web Api method with ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a C# WebAPI project with a method that uses a custom ModelBinder for its input parameter. When I look at the Swagger UI that Swashbuckle generates, rather than having a single "body" parameter, all of the properties' of the method's parameters are listed out separately. If I get rid of the [ModelBinder] attribute and switch to using the [FromBody] attribute, the Swagger UI shows the right thing. I have to use the [ModelBinder] attribute, so switching that out isn't an option.

Is there a way to make Swashbuckle generate the "[FromBody] attribute style" single parameter rather than the multiple parameters that it's doing?

Comment: Why don't you just chain them like IHttpActionResult Foo([FromBody][ModelBinder]SomeModel model) ?

Comment: Although it fixed the Swagger UI, it completely breaks the API itself... `"ExceptionMessage": "Can't bind parameter 'message' because it has conflicting attributes on it."`

Comment: Can you include the full sample (model, modelbinder, api method signature) ?

Comment: @HenryC Did you find a fix for this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ondrej is right.  Just chain them:

```
IHttpActionResult Foo([FromBody][ModelBinder]SomeModel model)
```

Comment: That might lead to error when invoking to the API since ModelBinder.AllowMultiple = false. so that any invoke to the API will lead to 500 response.

Comment: Works for me by using [FromQuery]

Answer (score 0):

Want to add that for Swashbuckle the order of attributes is important:

```
IActionResult Foo([FromBody, ModelBinder(typeof(SomeModelBinder))]SomeModel model)
```

will produce a correct OpenApi schema with SomeModel ref in requestBody.

But

```
IActionResult Foo([ModelBinder(typeof(SomeModelBinder)), FromBody]SomeModel model)
```

will produce an OpenApi schema with SomeModel defined as a query parameter